# How to stop Google Cloud from automatically resetting app data?

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform

I have a flask app that I'm using Google Cloud to host. Part of its data is an SQL database that is updated by user actions. However, I am finding that this database is being regularly reset to its original value every few days. Is there a way to disable this functionality so that any user data added during a session is saved to the cloud?

For reference, here is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app --timeout 300

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3


manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Comment: Do you mean you have in memory database with your app?

Comment: It's a sql database that I uploaded with the rest of the project, but I modify as the users take actions. I think that should be stored as website data, not in memory, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You mean you put your SQL database in your Container that you deploy on App Engine flex?

Comment: yes, I uploaded it as one of the files (along with the main.py script and templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine instances restart at least once a week. I'm unable to find this piece of doc again. But the instance need to be patched and have other maintenances operation, that's why it's roughly once a week.

In addition, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed#instance_uptime) mention clearly that, after a while, the uptime is now longer guarantee: physical outage or maintenance can occur

---

In addition, the principle of serverless application is to be stateless. It can scale up and down more easily without any disk attachment, concurrent read or whatever.

All the data loaded on your App Engine instance live in memory and are swapped when the instances is shut down. And because the containers are immutable, your data are definitively lost

Therefore, you have to design your application to store the data outside the serverless service, in a managed database like Cloud SQL for instance.